# How do I bundle only a range of changesets?

Tags: mercurial, bundle

I made some changes to my working repository and added a few small (2kb-10kb) python files. Then I bundled my changes:

```
hg bundle --base 100:120 nameofbundle.hg
```

My bundle seems to be 20MB. When I run:

```
hg diff -r 100:120
```

I can see all the changes I made in the python files but still it does not explain the 20MB size. There may be a chance that I may have added another file thus causing this strange size, is there any way of viewing this file or the files which are being tracked (from r100-120)?

I hope I have made this clear, I am still a newbie at mercurial.

---

EDIT

When I run

```
hg bundle --base 119:120 nameofbundle.hg
hg bundle --base 118:120 nameofbundle.hg
```

I get 439 change sets found for both when I have just edited 8 lines in the python files for both change sets. I do not understand these changes are not displaying in the diff?

Comment: Are you trying to create a bundle containing revisions `100:120`? You should pass `bundle` the `--rev` flag; `--base` is for specifying that the remote repository *already has* those revisions, so they should be excluded from the bundle. The 20MB is presumably from changesets that *aren't ancestors* of the `base` you're specifying, i.e. children or changesets on other branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look in the bundle with the following [command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LookingIntoBundles)

```
hg in nameofbundle.hg
```

It'll show the changesets in the given bundle file.

Comment: It says `comparing with nameofbundle.hg
searching for changes
no changes found`

Comment: Likely because you took it from the same repo you're comparing against. Try a repo that only has up to 99 (one less than where the bundle starts) and see what you get.

Comment: Thank you, I compared the bundles and found I was specifying the wrong base and revision. See question.

Comment: This does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

[As noted by the OP]

---

The command should have been

```
hg bundle -r 120 --base 100 nameofbundle.hg
```

This bundled only the 20 change sets and reducing the size to a mere 16k.